# Visual Studio 2012 Team Explorer pin status

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and really like the posibility to pin tabs in UI.

For code files, the pin status is remembered when restarting Visual Studio, but pages like Team Explorer and Source Control Explorer do not have the pinned status remembered. Is this a bug or can it be changed somehow?

Best regards,

Benny Tordrup

Comment: Best I have found this is a bug, and is still present in VS2013. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806922/team-explorer-source-control-explorer-do-not-stay-pinned-on-restart